# Sitecore date comparison doesn't return expected results

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm trying to return a list of courses using an iqueryable query but am having issues with some date comparisons.

I'm currently using the code

```
query = query.Where(r => r.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow);
```

which returns courses with dates in the future, however it will not return courses that end on the same day with a time ending later than the time returned by DateTime.UtcNow.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I've just used Luke to check the index and if I use

```
end_date:[20170531t092205609z TO *]
```

I get back the exact results I need, however in the logs the actual query uses

```
+end_date:[20170531t092205609z TO *] +_template:a84b75fccac64eafa746f4b71e628adc - Filter :
```

I then get more results back including the course I was missing.

a) Why do I get more results back using the second query?
b) Why is it that in my C# code the results returned do not match the search results?

Comment: Can you check in search log file what is the query which is sent to the index?

Comment: @MarekMusielak This was sent 28688 10:22:05 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (website_web_event_search_index): +end_date:[20170531t092205609z TO *] +_template:a84b75fccac64eafa746f4b71e628adc - Filter :

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue and described our solution here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2015/12/sitecore-lucene-index-and-datetime.html.

Our problems had 2 reasons:

- The first reason is that Sitecore stores its DateTimes in UTC (which was an hour difference with our local time)
- Second reason was that Sitecore uses "t" in the dates as lowercase in the query. In my index however they are all uppercase. If I try the query with Luke it does give me the wrong results indeed.. When I alter the query in Luke to use uppercase T it works correctly..

The easiest solution we found was a format attribute in the index config:

```xml
<field fieldName="datefrom" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" 
format="yyyyMMdd" type="System.DateTime" 
settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
```

(note the format="...")

Comment: The thing is i do get results back even with the lowercase t